# Unload JS loaded via load() to avoid duplicates?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm building a dynamic website that loads all pages inside a "body" div via jquery's load(). The problem is I have a script looped with setInterval inside the loaded PHP page, the reason being I want the script loaded only when that page is displayed. Now I discovered that the scripts keep running even after "leaving" the page (loading something else inside the div without refresh) and if I keep leaving / returning the loops stack up flooding my server with GET requests (from the javascript).

What's a good way to unload all JS once you leave the page? I could do a simple dummy var to not load scripts twice, but I would like to stop the loop after leaving the page because it's causing useless traffic and spouting console errors as elements it's supposed to fill are no longer there.

Sorry if this has already been asked, but it's pretty hard to come up with keywords for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) why don't you try with `clearInterval`? 
2) if you have a general (main) `function a( ) { ... }` doing something you can just override it with `function a() { };` doing nothing
3) if you null the references to something it will be garbage collected

no code provided, so no more I can do to help you

Comment: No code needed, I will change and adapt what I have based on recommendations. clearInterval sounds good, I'll go with that. Also thanks for the overriding trick, I did now know that's how js works.

Comment: all genaral functions and vars are defined in `window` ... so, if you have a general function named `doSomething`, you can access it by `window.doSomething` ... or clear it by setting `window.doSomething = undef;`

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like you need to reevaluate your design. Either you need to drop ajax, or you need to not have collisions in you method names.

You can review this link: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml

Which gives information on how to remove the javascript from the DOM. However, modern browsers will leave the code in memory on the browser.

Comment: leaving them in the memory is fine since they're small and irrelevant (couple of kb). What I care about is stopping them from running. Can you give me a hint on how to use the info in this link for inline javascript? The problem is I have to generate it via PHP, as the loop has a variable number of requests in it based on database data

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not dealing with real page loads/unloads I would build a system that simulates an unload event.

```
var myUnload = (function () {
  var queue = [],
    myUnload = function () {
      queue.forEach(function (unloadFunc) {
        undloadFunc();
      });
      queue = [];
    };

  myUnload.add = function (unloadFunc) {
    queue.push(unloadFunc);
  };
  return myUnload;
}());
```

The code that loads the new pages should just run `myUnload()` before it loads the new page in.

```
function loadPage(url) {
  myUnload();
  $('#page').load(url);
}
```

Any code that is loaded by a page can call `myUnload.add()` to register a cleanup function that should be run when a new page is loaded.

```
// some .js file that is loaded by a page
(function () {
  var doSomething = function () {
      // do something here
    },
    timer = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);

  // register our cleanup callback with unload event system
  myUnload.add(function () {
    // since all of this code is isolated in an IIFE,
    // clearing the timer will remove the last reference to
    // doSomething and it will automatically be GCed
    // This callback, the timer var and the enclosing IIFE
    // will be GCed too when myUnload sets queue back to an empty array.
    clearInterval(timer);
  });
}());
```

Comment: So each subpage should contain it's own "destroy" function that clears the scripts the same page loaded? And when another subpage is loaded, this function will call the destroy function? This is very useful as I was wondering how to integrate all these pages in a non-hardcoded way